# How to combine variable length arguments with keyword arguments in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

```
def addv(a,b,*args):
    sum = a + b
    for x in args:
        sum += x
    return sum

addv(b = 1,a = 2) # This is valid
addv(args = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),b = 9, a = 10) #This is giving me unexpected keyword argument.
```

I learned that keyword arguments are essentially passed as tuples. So, in an attempt to combine both keyword and variable arguments, I did the above experiment.

Is there any way to do such a kind of thing or all variable arguments must be passed to the end while calling a function.

Comment: Your first example doesn't seem valid since the positional arguments follow keyword arguments.

Comment: Yes. I just corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `**` operator to catch key word arguments. like this:

```
def addv(*args, **kwargs):
    result = 0
    for x in args:
        result += x
    for x in kwargs.values():
        result += x
    return result
```

Or a shorter way (suggested by Delirious Lettuce):

```
def addv(*args, **kwargs):
    return sum(args) + sum(kwargs.values())
```

---

Now you can do this:

```
addv(b = 1, a = 2) # Outputs: 3
addv(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, b = 9, a = 10) # Outputs: 55
```

Comment: `sum` as a variable name?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce oh, that's what you mean, I just copied the OP's code not noticing that xD

Comment: Instead of saying "you are kidding", why not just say: "it's bad practice to overshadow built-in variable names"?

Comment: No problem! I just meant that you could simplify it like this if you use `sum` properly. `return sum(args) + sum(kwargs.values())`